# How to add a third party into a live outbound call using Twilio and Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have an application built in Ruby ​On Rails where i be able to call members that are stored in a database, to call these members i am using TwilioWebRTC, making a request to a TwiML app, which returns this code:

```
member = Member.find_by_id params[:id]
client = Client.find_by_id params[:client_id]
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Say 'Hello. Connecting with the member now.', :voice => 'alice'
  r.Dial :record => 'record-from-answer',:callerId => client.twilio_number do |d|
    d.Number member.mobile_phone
  end
end
```

The problem comes when in a certain moment i have to redirect this call to another number. Currently to redirect the call i make a request to a route, updating the call with this:

```
@call = @client.account.calls.get(outgoing_call.sid)
@call.update(:url => "#{ENV['APP_BASE_URL']}/twilio/redirect_call?client_id=#{params[:client_id]}",
             :method => "POST")
```

that url return this part:

```
client = Client.find_by_id params[:client_id]
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Dial :record => 'record-from-answer' do |d|
    d.Number client.redirect_number
  end
end
```

This redirects my call, but disconnects my outgoing call on the client
I need the call can be redirected without being hung on the client, so, how can i add  a third person to the outbound call without it disconnecting ?, I have searched a lot of documentation but all work is with incoming calls.
In this case it is i who call both, the client and the other participant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you need three people in a conversation then you need to use [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference) to connect them.

For the initial call, instead of dialling the user into a one on one call, you should have them enter the conference and simultaneously dial the second party:

```
member = Member.find_by_id params[:id]
client = Client.find_by_id params[:client_id]
room_id = "#{member.id}-#{client.id}"
@client.calls.create(
  :to => member.mobile_phone,
  :from => client.twilio_number,
  :url => "#{ENV['APP_BASE_URL']}/twilio/conference?room_id=#{room_id}"
)
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Say 'Hello. Connecting with the member now.', :voice => 'alice'
  r.Dial do |d|
    d.Conference room_id, :record => 'record-from-start'
  end
end
```

You then need a route for "/twilio/conference" that reads the room_id from the URL and returns the same TwiML for the conference.

```
room_id = params[:room_id]
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Dial do |d|
    d.Conference room_id
  end
end
```

Then, when you want to add another caller to the call, instead of redirecting, you just create a new call to them that also uses that conference route and room id.

```
client = Client.find_by_id params[:client_id]
room_id = params[:room_id]
@client.calls.create(
  :to => client.redirect_number,
  :from => client.twilio_number,
  :url => "#{ENV['APP_BASE_URL']}/twilio/conference?room_id=#{room_id}"
)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: yeap , it works , thanks a lot , but i have a question, when i call the member, The program asks him to press a key to enter the conference, there is a way to disable this?, and the client simply enters without press anything?

Comment: Have you upgraded your account? That shouldn't happen unless you've programmed it to ask the user to dial a number.